# LinkedIn API with pengwynn's LinkedIn gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, linkedin-api

I need some help with getting to some elements in this Nokogiri output from the LinkedIn API (this is more a Ruby/Nokogiri question than it is a LinkedIn API question)

```
#<LinkedIn::Company:0x00000102c466e0 @doc=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x94017c5c     name="company" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x94017978 "\n        ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x94017770 name="id" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x940173ec "1234">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x940165c8 "\n        ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x94016320 name="name" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x94015d30 "Company Foo">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x94015768 "\n        ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x94015560 name="size" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x94014ffc "501-1000 employees">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x94003770 "\n        ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x94002438 name="type" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x817f9b7c "Public Company">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x817f95c8 "\n        ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x817f93e8 name="industry" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x817f91a4 "SomeIndustry">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x817f8f4c "\n        ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x817f8e48 name="ticker" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x817f8b3c "FOO">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x817f88d0 "\n      ">]>]>
```

I am able to get to some attributes of the company easily - these are company.name, company.type and company.industry but the others like company.id, company.size and company.ticker all lead to a NoMethod error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `size' for #<LinkedIn::Company:0x00000102c42310>
```

Why is that - I can *see* it in the object but can't access it! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you using for the call to `company` in the gem?

Comment: I am actually a  Profile call with positions as a field selector: http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~(:positions) and each position has a company section where there is id, name, size, ticker, industry etc.

Comment: Can you post your code that you use to get to the `LinkedIn::Company` xml?

Comment: Sure. I first use OmniAuth and OmniAuth-LinkedIn to get the token and secret and persist them in my User model. After that, client = LinkedIn::Client.new('my_app_consumer_key','my_app_consumer_secret') follower by client.authorize_from_access(user.token,user.secret) and finally the actual call which is profile = client.profile(:id => user.uid, :fields => ['positions'])

Comment: i had a problem with calling "size" on certain hash objects because i had to disambiguate between array.size and array['size'].

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure Nokogiri is the way to go. I used the straight LinkedIn::Mash object and did this:

```
user = client.profile(:fields => %w(positions))
companies = user.positions.all.map{|t| t.company}
companies.each do |company|
    #ap company.inspect
    #ap "meow\n"
    if company.id
        ap "ID: #{company.id}"
    else
        ap "ID not present"
    end
    if company.industry
        ap "Industry: #{company.industry}"
    else
        ap "Industry not present"
    end
    if company.name
        ap "Name: #{company.name}"
    else
        ap "Name not present"
    end
    if company.size
        ap "Size: #{company.size}"
    else
        ap "Size not present"
    end
    if company.type
        ap "Type: #{company.type}"
    else
        ap "Type not present"
    end
    if company.ticker
        ap "Ticker: #{company.ticker}"
    else
        ap "Ticker not present"
    end 
end
```

The attributes are not always present so I did the if/else weirdness to show that I was at least getting the object. Anyway, if present I am getting the attrs and printing them.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I saw that the gem on github had a v2-stable branch and when I used that, it seemed to work ok